# increase sensitivity to user touch

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom table layout where each row is a slide-able view. Everything is working fine, except there is a continuous delay between when a user starts sliding a when the view starts moving. Is there a way to reduce that starting delay?

I am building my table layout inside an async task. So at first I was getting an error about needing to use a looper. Since I didn't know how to do that I use `runOnUiThread` to handle the problem code. So now I am wondering if that's the reason for the slow response to touch. Here is the code

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
handler.post(mResizeViews);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The question may be "What happen when user sliding?"
if you do some heavily task such as inflate layout when user start slide.

So, check what happen when user start sliding