# How would I use a Looper with an asyncTask?

Tags: android, android-layout, event-handling, android-asynctask, looper

How would I use a Looper with an asyncTask?

The doImBackground method is called to programmatically create a TableLayout called MyResultTable. The MyResultTable, in turn, has a handler that is called by onTouch during `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`.

After getting complaints about using handle inside asynchTask, I decide to run handler on UIThread. But that's causing my onTouch method to have slow response. So my question is, how do I use a looper with an asyncTask?

**UIThread code:**

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
handler.post(mResizeViews);
  }
});
```

**My Looper attempt: (not working: blank screen)**

```
protected MyResultTable doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Looper.prepare();
            MyResultTable table = new MyResultTable(context, other);
            Looper.loop();
            return tabl;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

> How would I use a Looper with an asyncTask?

You wouldn't.

> The doImBackground method is called to programmatically create a TableLayout called MyResultTable.

That is not an appropriate role for `doInBackground()`. Use `doInBackground()` for slow things: network I/O, disk I/O, etc. Use `onPostExecute()` for generating the UI ("a TableLayout called MyResultTable") based upon the data retrieved by `doInBackground()`.

> The MyResultTable, in turn, has a handler that is called by onTouch during MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE.

That does not make much sense. You use a `Handler` to forward events to the main application thread from a background thread. Your `onTouchEvent()` is called on the main application thread, and therefore it does not need a `Handler`.

Comment: Are you sure? I know you usually have great answers. But I always assemble my tables in the background and then use `onPostExecute` to pass the custom table to the linearLayout holding it. Otherwise android tends to say my UI is working too much.

Comment: @CoteMounyo: "Otherwise android tends to say my UI is working too much" -- use tools like Traceview to find the real reason behind performance issues.

Comment: Ok. So I try your suggestions. And it works (+1). No complaint from android about UI working hard. But my slider is still not smooth. It takes a while to start moving and then jump to where user has displaced finger. Ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958671/increase-sensitivity-to-user-touch